# Javascript Filter Object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript

I'm mapping over an array that comes with objects containing items. Each item has it's category. I would like to generate an array of categories each one bringing it's items. Here is the approach that I took so far:

```
...Typescript
    categories.map((item: Items) => {
        response.push({ title: item.category });
    });
...
```

```
[
  {
    category: 'Food',
    name: 'Some food1'
  },
  {
    category: 'Food',
    name: 'Some food2'
  },
  ...
]
```

The result must be like this:

```
[
  {
    title: 'Food',
    items: [
      {
        name: 'Some food1'
      },
      {
        name: 'Some food2'
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: `map` is meant to transform and return data, not for side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to write a custom function, but the easiest way would be to use Lodash's [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)

```js
import { groupBy } from 'lodash'

const arr = [
  {
    category: 'Food',
    name: 'Some food1'
  },
  {
    category: 'Food',
    name: 'Some food2'
  },
]

const groups = groupBy(arr, 'category')
// returns {
//   Food: [
//     { category: 'Food', name: 'Some food1' },
//     { category: 'Food', name: 'Some food2' },
//   ]
// }

const groupedArr = Object.entries(groups).map(([title, items]) => ({ title, items }))
// returns [
//   {
//     title: 'Food',
//     items: [
//       { category: 'Food', name: 'Some food1' },
//       { category: 'Food', name: 'Some food2' },
//     ]
//   },
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, pure JS, but you probably could use lodash's groupBy function:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

```
const data = [
    {
        category: 'Food',
        name: 'Some food1'
    },
    {
        category: 'Food',
        name: 'Some food2'
    },
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const {category, ...itemData} = item;

    let itemWithCategory = acc.find((elem) => elem.title === category )
    if(!itemWithCategory) {
        itemWithCategory = {title: category, items: []}
        acc.push(itemWithCategory)

    }
    itemWithCategory.items.push(itemData)
    return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet, that should solve your problem -

```
   function filterAndMerge(data) {
        let result = {};
        data.forEach((each) => {
            if (!result[each.category]) {
                result[each.category] = [];
            }
            result[each.category].push(each.name);
        });
        const formattedResult = Object.keys(result).map((title) => ({
            title,
          items: result[title]
        }));
        return formattedResult;
    }
```

The idea is to club the `name`s into the corresponding `category` by pushing it into the `result` object. Later, we are formatting the result back into an array with `title` and `items` by mapping through its keys.